# SM N900A rooted Google Play Store Immediate Shutdown Hosts File Deleted

Tags: google-play-store, hosts

Recently i rooted my phone. Note 3 att. using kingo root.it worked fine google play was fine but after some days some shitty thing started to happen and my facebook, gapps were all shut.no updating. when i opened my google play it simply shut down almost instantaneously."Google play has stopped working" was all i got and sometimes not even that. i deleted google play from system downloaded new one also deleted play services and downloaded latest ones.it didnt work "connection failed retry" and "unreliable network" problems. finally i did some research and found this "root browser" and deleted hosts file from system/etc, rebooted and bam google play worked i started getting updates notifications and i thought it went fine but after i opened google play for about 10 seconds after accepting the google terms of use it crashed and every then and now it keeps crashing immediately as i open them. i dont have google play sign in problems or syncing problems like before all things fine just the play store crashes freaking spontaneously. IDK if its the host files ive deleted or play store being faulty. I am SERIOUSLY PISSED non stop 2 days of googling(never googled so long in my entire life) and im tired of this. ANYONE HAS ANY IDEA how am i gonna fix this. and please spare me the cache, data wipe and factory reset and rebooting bullshit. ANY HELP IS TOTALLY APPRECIATED. HELLLP PLEASE.

Comment: Not really enough info. Can you supply a copy of your build.prop (In /system) and your hosts file? It is bad practise to delete the file, you can just delete its contents EXECPT the top line. Always works here.    Cant be the play store if you have a fresh install of it.

Comment: I am so sorry to be this late. And as for my problem i managed to tackle with it from some guy( I swear i had literally memorized his name for 10 times)over the internet. Actually all i needed to do was get link2sd ,shift playstore and google play services from system into the sd and reboot and again put it back to the system and voila! It worked like a charm.Guess the gapps need to be jolted into the system so as not to have a connection timed out error and the crashing THANK YOU FOR YOUR ATTENTION THOUGH.

Comment: No problem. Since that method worked, add it as an answer and mark it to help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually all i needed to do was get link2sd ,shift playstore and google play services from system into the sd and reboot and again put it back to the system and voila! It worked like a charm.Guess the gapps need to be jolted into the system so as not to have a connection timed out error.HOPE THIS HELPS!!